# Making Base Class Conversion Functions Public with a Protected Inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class inheriting from another.  I don't want users of this class to accidentally use base-class functions on the child object.  The obvious answer is to make the inheritance protected or private.

However, I *do* want implicit casting from the child object to the base class.  The default implementation of this cast is hidden in most contexts as it's given the protected/private status, and attempting to define a user conversion throws the warning that
`"converting ‘B’ to a reference to a base class ‘A’ will never use a type conversion operator [-Wclass-conversion]"`

Fair enough.  With that avenue closed to me, I must turn here and ask: is there some way to reclassify the default type conversion into the public space so that implicit casting can live on?

As an example of what I'm trying to get working:

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        
    }
    A(A& otherA)
    {
        
    }
};

class B : protected A
{
public:
    operator A& ()
    {
        return *this;
    }
    
};

int main() {
    B guy;
    A otherguy(guy);
}
```

Sadly, I can't just declare the offending functions within the base class as protected: I want them available if the user explicitly casts to that base class.  In my particular case, B contains no data and is merely a convenience/safety wrapper around A, so I don't need to worry about slicing or otherwise losing any information by allowing this cast.  I just don't want users mistaking the backend API (which is exposed currently via public inheritance) for parts of the more user-friendly wrapper API.

Comment: If the goal is to make the user acknowledge that they're converting, have you considered just having an explicit function, say, `B.convert_to_a`?. Having to write `guy.convert_to_a()` makes it pretty clear that I understand the consequences of the conversion.

Comment: I have a function like so, which provides the explicit cast that I expect them to do to get into that backend API.  However, I have no desire to rewrite every use of B in its current implicitly-casted nature to call that explicit function.  Lots of functions that request an A are currently accepting Bs in my codebase.
I also don't want to normalize calling the explicit conversion, as requiring it in each of those cases would do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want *in the way you've asked to do it*.

I'd use encapsulation instead of inheritance:

```
class A {
public:
    T func1(); // should be visible via B
    void func2(); // should not be visible via B
};

class B { // note: not inheriting from A
    A base; // B explicitly defines its "base class sub-object"
public:
    // provide access to base class sub-object
    operator A&() { return base; }

    // provide access to func1
    T func1() { return base.func1(); }
};

void use(A &a) { a.func2(); }

int main() { 
    B b;

    b.func1(); // no problem
    // b.func2(); // won't work;

    use(b);    // no problem. Uses our conversion operator
}
```